# How does log come into play?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, reference-works

[image]

$$\begin{align*}I & = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \dfrac{\sin^{-1} x}{x}\ dx - \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\tan^{-1} x}{x} \ dx  \\ & = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \dfrac{\theta \cos \theta}{\sin \theta} \ d\theta - \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \dfrac{\theta \sec^2 \theta}{\tan \theta} \ d\theta \\ & = \color{red}{-\dfrac{\pi}{4} \ln 2} -2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln \sin \theta \ d\theta + \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln \tan \theta \ d\theta \\ & = -\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln \sin 2\theta \ d\theta \\ & = \dfrac{\pi}{4} \ln 2\end{align*}$$

Could someone tell me how the author of this book (Vikas Gupta, Advanced Problems in Mathematics) came up with the 3rd step containing log? Is it some sort of standard result?

What makes me ask is cause of the term $-\frac\pi4 \log 2$

Comment: @Henry I was talking about the step containiing the initial term as -pi/4ln2

Comment: Looks like integration by parts, where $u=\theta$ and $dv$ is the rest of the integral. The anti-derivative of $\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$ is $\ln(\sin\theta).$

Comment: Quite true, but I'm just unable to get that expression

Comment: Be specific. Which expression? What I wrote or something above?

Comment: Presumably the $-\frac\pi4\ln2$ comes from evaluating $uv\vert_0^{\pi/4}$ in both integration by parts steps.

Comment: -pi/4 ln2 - 2*(integral of ln(sintheta)dtheta + integral of lntan theta dtheta

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I see let me just try it one more time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well, your question is about

$$2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \dfrac{\theta \cos \theta}{\sin \theta} \ d\theta - \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \dfrac{\theta \sec^2 \theta}{\tan \theta} \ d\theta$$

Turning into
$$-\dfrac{\pi}{4} \ln 2 -2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln \sin \theta \ d\theta + \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln \tan \theta \ d\theta$$

---

From integrating by parts:

$$\int u \ dv = u \cdot v - \int v \ du$$

Therefore

$$\begin{align*}\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \underbrace{\theta}_{u} \cdot \underbrace{\dfrac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta} \ d\theta}_{dv} & =  \left[\theta \cdot \ln \left(\sin \theta\right)\right]_{0}^{\pi/4} - \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln \left(\sin \theta\right)\ d\theta \\
& = \dfrac{\pi}{4}\cdot \ln \left(\sin \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) - \underbrace{0 \cdot \ln \left(\sin 0\right)}_{\text{careful}} - \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln \left(\sin \theta\right)\ d\theta \end{align*}
$$

The limit which I put **careful** is $0$ from [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+x*ln%28sin%28x%29%29+as+x-%3E0%2B).

Now, the log term is:

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\pi}{4}\cdot \ln \left(\sin \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) & = \dfrac{\pi}{4}\cdot \ln \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ & = \dfrac{\pi}{4}\left(-\ln \sqrt{2}\right) \\ & = \dfrac{-\pi}{4} \ln \sqrt{2} \\ & = \dfrac{-\pi}{4} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} \ln 2 \\ & = \dfrac{-\pi}{8} \cdot \ln 2\end{align}$$

Therefore:

$$\boxed{2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \dfrac{\theta \cos \theta}{\sin \theta} \ d\theta = 2\cdot \dfrac{-\pi}{8} \cdot \ln 2 - 2\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln \left(\sin \theta\right)\ d\theta}$$